# fastq file format unknown

Tags: sequence-alignment, ngs, trimming, bowtie2

I have paired-end fastq files some of which seem to be in a weird format (from a collaborator, not a public database). When I `cat` the file I get what seem to me to be binary syntax but not sure?

[image: weird output]

However when I `cat` into the other pair-end the output seems fine

[image: correct output]

Any help/suggestion/solution would be greatly appreciated.

It does seem to be compressed with a missing suffix:

```
file pair1.fastq
   pair1.fastq: data.
```

Comment: When I run `file pair1.fastq` on the problem fastq file I get the following output: `pair1.fastq: data`. When I run it on the other pair-end file which doesn't have any issues I get `pair2.fastq: gzip compressed data, extra field`

Comment: `gzip compressed data, extra field` is probably produced using `bgzip`. If it were simple `gzip`, the `extra field` part wouldn't be there.

Answer (score 3):

This indeed looks like some sort of binary file. I have seen bunch of those when people renamed `.fastq.gz` to `.fastq` without actually uncompressing them. However, as you say, this is not your case, as `file pair1.fastq` would identify the file as `gzip compressed data`.

Looking at possible return values of `file` comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151008/linux-file-command-classifying-files), `data` basically mean the command could not figure out anything about it beside being some sort of binary data file, but I suspect it probably somehow broken file. Honestly, at this point I think you should check the source of the data. If it's from a public database, re-download the data. If it's your own sequencing, contact the sequencing provider and check the data with them. I don't see any way to rescue this file (which does not necerasrily mean there is nothing you can do).

Comment: thanks again for the quick response. I was afraid that that might be the case. unfortunately the file came from a collaborator not a public database. I will have to bring that to their attention.